# Remove markers on Google Map after 'n' days to remove congestion for real-time data

Tags: javascript, google-maps, date, google-maps-markers

I have markers on my Google Map plotted based on the location (lat, lng) from API JSON data. I want to remove only those markers that were plotted on the Map before 30 days from the current date so that as I keep populating my Map, the markers get removed automatically and looks neat without congestion.

I tried something like this in JavaScript:

```
var today = new Date(); //current date
var expire = new Date(current + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); //expire after 30 days




if(today == expire){
  current = Date.now();
  setTimeout(function(){
      for(i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++){
          gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
      }       
   }, 2000);
}
```

"current" variable's value is not defined in the beginning. How to make this possible?

Comment: @charlietfl "Expire" will be a constant date that is 30 days ahead the starting date. Suppose starting date for a particular marker is Apr 21, then expire date will be May 21. "Today" will keep getting updated to Apr 22, 23, and so on. Once it becomes May 21 (expiry date), I want that particular marker to disappear. I use "Today" for finding the updated date. Am I wrong?

Comment: my point is you define `today` and don't use it when it could be used in the next line

Comment: Also don't see how the data gets on map in first place. Filter the data before adding markers

Comment: Dude if I use it in the next line, then expire's value will get changed. Expire should remain a constant for 30 days.

Comment: `var expire = new Date(today.getTime() +(...))` ... also note comparing two different objects won't do what you expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save `current` in the browser do the following:

```
var current;
if (localStorage.getItem('current')) {
    current = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('current'));
} else {
    current = Date.now();
    localStorage.setItem('current', JSON.stringify(current));
}
```

Comment: If I do var current=Date.now() in the beginning, my "current" will get updated every time the function is called right? It should not get changed.

Comment: @RagapriyaSivakumar If it is inside of the function block, yes. You will need to set it outside of the function that gets called everytime.

Comment: My script function gets executed every time the web page is loaded. A user can reload my web page any time and gets to see the real-time markers on the map. so your solution is not feasible. "current" will get changed every time.

Comment: Smart idea to use browser cache! Thanks Marcus.